# Heat equation in polar coordinates with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have the heat equation with no external heat term in polar coordinates which I have to solve on the unit disk.

$$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right) + \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2} \equiv\Delta u$$

The given initial and boundary conditions are the following:
$$u(1,\theta,t)=\sin 3\theta$$
$$u(r,\theta,0)= 0$$

I read about the approach of introducing a new variable $v(r,\theta,t)$ such that:

$$v(r,\theta,t)=u(r,\theta,t)-u_E(r,\theta)$$

where $u_E(r,\theta)$ is the equilibrium temperature distribution and $v(r,\theta,t)$ is supposed to have  homogeneous boundary conditions.

I understand that if the variables were in cartesian coordinates, owing to the fact that the equilibrium temperature distrubution turns out to be a linear distrubution when there is no external heat source, we can claim that:

$$v_{xx}=u_{xx},     v_{yy}=u_{yy},   v_{zz}=u_{zz}, v_{t} = u_{t}$$

But I am confused about what are their equivalents in polar coordinates? Although I think in polar coordinates $v_{rr} = u_{rr}$ and $v_{t} = u_{t}$ could be valid assumptions but I don't think $v_{\theta \theta} = u_{\theta \theta}$ is a valid assumption because the $\theta$ coordinate in general is not linear but a sinusoidal function in the solution expression. I don't have good reasons to set $(u_E)_{\theta \theta}=0$ in:

$$v_{\theta \theta} = u_{\theta \theta} - (u_E)_{\theta \theta}$$

So, how do I define the new variables to make the boundary value homogeneous for this nonhomogeneous boundary value problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, generally speaking for this kind of problems seperation of variables works very well.

So in order to end up with the equilibrium solution start with the defining equations:
$$
\Delta u_E(r,\theta)=0\\
u_E(1,\theta)=\sin(3\theta)
$$
Making the Ansatz $u_E(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ we can immediately deduct $\Theta(\theta)=\sin(3\theta)$ and $R(1)=1$ from the boundary condition. Since we would like our equilibrium solution to be smooth at the origin we additionally require $R(0)=0$. (Otherwise the function would jump when going over the origin in a straight line)

Inserting the Ansatz into the differential equation yields
$$
\dfrac{1}{r}\left(r R'(r)\sin(3\theta)\right)' - \dfrac{1}{r^2} R(r)9\sin(3\theta) = 0\\
\Leftrightarrow r(rR'(r))'= 9R(r)
$$
This linear ODE can be solved by the standard methods available and we end up with  $R(r)=r^3$.
Thus, the equilibrium solution reads $u_E(r,\theta)=r^3\sin(3\theta)$.